# Пустой кортеж в Python

Tags: python, кортежи

Почему в Python `()` - пустой кортеж, список с пустым кортежем внутри это `[()]`, но при этом при выполнении такого кода

```
l = [1,2,3]
l[:] = ()
print(l)
```

интерпретатор выведет пустой список? Функция `len()` также выдает, что список пустой

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что именно вас интересует? Расскажите подробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут надо понимать разница между присваиванием значения элементу списка, и присваиванием значения срезу списка.

Если перед "равно" у вас стоит один элемент списка, то значение справа от "равно" заменяет собой это значение:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[0] = ()
print(l)
# Выведет: [(), 2, 3]
```

Но если в левой части присваивания у вас стоит **срез** списка, то срез - это последовательность, и заменить его можно только другой последовательностью. Поэтому интерпретатор рассматривает правую часть присваивания как последовательность, элементы которой надо присвоить срезу:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l[:2] = (9, 9)
print(l)
# Выведет: [9, 9, 3, 4, 5]
```

В примере выше видно, что вместо среза первых двух элементов подставился не сам кортеж, а содержащиеся в нём элементы.

С пустым кортежем всё то же самое, только элементов в нём нет, и вместо взятого среза подставляется ничего.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l[:2] = ()
print(l)
# Выведет: [3, 4, 5]
```

Соответственно, если вашей целью является заменить срез на один элемент, представляющий собой пустой кортеж, то в правой части должен быть не просто пустой кортеж, а последовательность, содержащая один пустой кортеж:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[:] = [()]
print(l)
# Выведет: [()]
```